# Which browsers handle `Content-Encoding: gzip` and which of them has any special requirements on encoding quality?

Tags: gzip

I am creating a "hand made" HTTP 1.0, 1.1 server. I recently integrated zip lib so now I can stream encoded gziped data in and out. I wonder which major browsers (alive ones - IE6-IE10, Chrome, FF, etc.) send `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, ...` and so can handle `Content-Encoding: gzip` today? Which of them send any quality expectations? Which of them can send encoded gziped post request and multypart/form data to my server?

Comment: Shouldn't you be relying on the Accept-Encoding header anyway? Or are you just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: @Flimzy If you're storing files that have been encoded in advance (which you might do to reduce CPU load, to decrease disk space usage, to increase the level of compression, or because you're serving files from an entirely static server), then you don't really have the luxury to adhere to the Accept-Encoding header. If you can obey the header, of course you should, but given the virtually-universal support of gzip nowadays, it's okay to build your website to require gzip support.

Comment: @haydenschiff of course you can still honor the accept header. If you're storing gzipped data, you are already prepared to unzip it to serve it if the accept header dictates.

Answer (score 57):

Basically every browser nowadays supports deflate/gzip. [This page](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm) lists many browsers and version numbers. Here's a summary plus some newer browsers:

- Netscape 6+ (Netscape 4-5 does, but with some bugs).
- Internet Explorer 5.5+ (July 2000) and IE 4 if set to HTTP/1.1.
- Opera 5+ (June 2000)
- Lynx 2.6+ (some time before 1999)
- Firefox 0.9.5+ (October 2001)
- Chrome since forever
- Safari since forever (as far as I can tell)

As you can see: for almost 15 years, there's full support, and nobody uses a more than 15 year old browser.

Comment: +1 I was kind of confused, as this seems like a non-existent problem. @user1049847 maybe you need to expand your question above?

Comment: And to add to this, no browser will send a gzip compressed request but almost all accept a gzip compressed response. See "[Why can't browser send gzip request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424917/why-cant-browser-send-gzip-request)" on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Su' is right - any browser that supports gzip **will send the Accept-Encoding header** so you don't need to care exactly which browsers support this. Send gzip when they tell you they're able to receive it.

Comment: The question is relevant. If you are serving static files from Amazon S3, MS Azure and others (as many do) you won't be able to dynamically respond to the accept-encoding header. Also compressing on the fly puts an added load on the CPU.

Comment: @QFDev if you are serving static files, you can create one version that is gzipped and one that is not and check for accept-encoding/gzip and change the static files served accordingly.

Comment: The answer may be misleading. Even if the browser does support gzip, there are other factors which can block it. See http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/11/11/whos-not-getting-gzip/

Comment: That blog-post is almost 7 years old and even back then the majority of problems were missing headers, not the missing ability to work with gzip-encoded content anyways. Also, a big part of the problem was IE6, wich nowadays is (practically) dead.

Comment: @JordanReiter It may be better to store just compressed static files given that decompression is typically faster than compression. In this way one can gain several benefits: rarely having to apply gzip (to decompress for those requests that aren't supporting gzip), minimizing storage, and allowing maximum compression (since one wouldn't have to worry about the compression rate/load time tradeoff, one could always use maximum compression).